How to ensure older parameters that are removed from ADF are removed from ARM template deployment task override parameters list also
We are deploying ADF as shown below:

the problem is -  even though some template parameters are removed from the ADF the still keep appearing in override parameters list when we click on the (3 dot symbol).
How can we get rid of them so that they don't appear again?
Thanks

Can you share the code here to check and resolve the issue. @azuresnowflake1

@jahnavi - do you mean YAML code ?

ARM code. @azuresnowflake1

can't share the code here as it is sensitive but the challenge is: older global parameters and ARM template params are removed but they still show up in override param list after clicking on ( 3 dots symbol) and this is the challenge

Ensure the parameters are removed from both template and template parameters. Click "Edit Override template parameters" (3 dot symbol). You will see warning message Parameters specified are not found in template and could fail the deployment and the deleted parameters will be marked with a red underline. Click the parameter name -> delete it -> Click OK. Then the parameter will be removed from override template parameters list.


precisely the problem.. they are not highlighted in red even though they are removed from the ARM Template Parameter file

Have you checked to see if they have been deleted from the template as well? Testing on my side, if a parameter is only removed from the template parameters, but is still in the template, the override template parameters list will not have any warnings and the deleted parameter will not be underlined.
